# Select query for filtering data from particular range of year and month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to display data from user selected year of March to next year of April(ex:if user selected 2017, then  need to select data from from 2017 march to april 2018 ). What is the best query for filtering it. It should be order by from selected year.

```
SELECT DATEPART(mm,submitted_date),SUM(total_count),YEAR(submitted_date)
FROM store_details 
WHERE YEAR(submitted_date) = '2017'  
AND  MONTH(submitted_date) >=3 
Group By YEAR(submitted_date),DATEPART(mm,submitted_date) 
Order By YEAR(submitted_date),DATEPART(mm,submitted_date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, later versions (2012+) of SQL Server have a nice built in function called `datefromparts`. However, since your question is tagged with [sql-server-2005](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2005) this doesn't help so much unless you can upgrade your database (and you really should think about it, since 2005 is no longer supported by Microsoft).

However, since you know you want all the data between March and April of next year, you can simply do this:

```
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH,submitted_date),SUM(total_count),YEAR(submitted_date)
FROM store_details 
WHERE submitted_date >= CAST(CAST(@Year as char(4)) + '-03-01 00:00:00' As datetime)  
WHERE submitted_date < CAST(CAST(@Year + 1 as char(4)) + '-04-01 00:00:00' As datetime)  

Group By YEAR(submitted_date),DATEPART(MONTH,submitted_date) 
Order By YEAR(submitted_date),DATEPART(MONTH,submitted_date)
```

(That is, assuming the user provides the year as an int value.)

Comment: shows Incorrect syntax near 'CAST', expected 'AS'.@Year is passing as 2017 in parmeterised query

Comment: I've closed the parenthesis too soon. Try now.

Comment: Got it. Please correct the Where with And in answer. WHERE submitted_date >= CAST(CAST(@Year as char(4)) + '-03-01 00:00:00' As datetime)  
AND  submitted_date < CAST(CAST(@Year + 1 as char(4)) + '-04-01 00:00:00' As datetime)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the starting month and date in hand, then I don't see why you can't just add an upper bound to the date in your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
    DATEPART(mm, submitted_date),
    SUM(total_count),
    YEAR(submitted_date)
FROM store_details 
WHERE
    (YEAR(submitted_date) = '2017' AND MONTH(submitted_date) >= 3) AND
    (YEAR(submitted_date) = '2018' AND MONTH(submitted_date) < 4)
GROUP BY
    YEAR(submitted_date),
    DATEPART(mm, submitted_date) 
ORDER BY
    YEAR(submitted_date),
    DATEPART(mm, submitted_date)
```